# XPath query. Preceding-sibling of a conditionally reduced set of nodes

Tags: xpath

I got html code like the following:

`<p style="margin:0 0 0.5em 0;"><b>Blablub</b></p>`
`<table> ... </table>`

Now I want to query the content of the `<b>` right above the table but only if the table does not have any attributes. I tried the following query:

//table[not(@*)]/preceding-sibling::p/b

If I remove the `preceding-sibling::p/b` part entirely it works. It gives me exactly the tables I need. However, if I use this query it gives me content of an `<b>` tag which precedes a table WITH attributes.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a correct XPath expression. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//table[not(@*)]/preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p]/b
```

This means: Select all `b` elements that are children of all `p` elements that are *the first* preceding sibling of a `table` that has no attributes.

**This is quite different from the problematic expression cited in the question**:

> ```
> //table[not(@*)]/preceding-sibling::p[1]/b
> ```

The latter selects the `b` children of the first `p` following sibling -- there is no guarantee that the first `p` following sibling is also the first element sibling.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to work, alhtough I don't really understand why it didn't work before :). I'm using the query '//table[not(@*)]/preceding-sibling::p[1]/b' which should be the same as yours.

Comment: @Christian-Ziegler: These two expressions are not equivalent. Yours selects the `b` children of the first `p` preceding sibling. Mine selects the `b` children of the first element sibling, if it happens to be a `p`.